# (tumblr) How to hide {NoteCount} if there are no notes on a post?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I want to hide the {NoteCount} or {NoteCountWithLabel} when there are no notes on a tumblr post, instead of displaying 0 or 0 notes.

This is for a new tumblr theme i'm building.

docs:https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

If this is possible can it be done in `javascript` or `css` ?

Comment: {block:NoteCount} read this at your given docs link

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation?

It says right there: `{block:NoteCount}`

> Rendered if this post has notes. Always wrap note counts in this block
>   so they will be properly hidden on non-post pages.

Comment: How to do it, in case for the "reblog" link in posts, not button?

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. The OP want's to hide the `{NoteCount}` if it it equal to zero. `{block:NoteCount}{/block:NoteCount}` only works for "posts" that do not have notes associated with them. ie. Ask pages and additional pages you add to your blog.